# Mouse cursor hotspot offset from visible cursor location

Tags: windows-10, mouse

I have 4 screens, 4k display in my laptop, 4k desktop monitor, HD desktop monitor and 800x480 USB monitor. Starting yesterday my mouse clicks happen away from the visible cursor but only on two of the screens. On the main laptop screen and USB display it works fine but on the 4k and HD external monitors Windows is showing the cursor in a different location than where clicks are registered. The monitors run at different scales but that doesn't seem to be the problem. I set all of them to 100% and rebooted and it had the same problem.

I have updated the mouse drivers and also switched to a different mouse and it had the same problem. I ran SFC /Scannow and it found a few corrupt files but nothing that would seem to impact this, I fixed them and rebooted but that didn't solve the problem. I also tried changing the cursors in the theme to different ones to see if they would work differently or fix the default cursors. That didn't help either, they all had this offset problem.

Another peculiarity is that when I move the cursor to the edge of an app to resize it the cursor disappears entirely instead of changing to the resize cursor. It does that on all monitors.

The problem becomes especially apparent when drawing in an app because the line appears in the wrong spot. It's also more obvious when moving the cursor to the edge of the screen, sometimes it goes past the edge and sometimes it can't make it to the edge. I grabbed some screenshots and pictures of both situations. When I did the drawing test it was extra weird because on the HD monitor only the cursor changed to the wait cursor but was a normal pointer on the other monitors.

Any ideas what might cause this or how to troubleshoot it? Getting kinda annoying to try to work when I have to guess where the click will land.

[image: Drawing]
[image: Cursor pictures]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting.

After a reboot my monitors were acting a bit funny so I unplugged my SIIG USB 3 hub which drives the 4k external monitor and HD monitor. After restarting the hub now the cursors have no trouble. Since I also just rebooted to install a Windows update I can't guarantee that it was the hub reboot that fixed it but it does seem likely since the two monitors that had the problem are the two that are driven by that hub.

Might be time for me to habitually reboot that hub every day.