# Mouse pointer location not accurate on new computer

Tags: display, mouse, windows-11

I have a weird issue since getting a new Windows 11 PC a couple months ago. The location of my mouse pointer on my monitor does not line up with where the click actually lands. The actual click location is about 1/4 inch up and to the left of the pointer icon. I have tried multiple mouses, tried the same mouses on my old machine, and changed the settings in Windows including the pointer scheme and the 'Enhance pointer precision' checkbox to no avail. I have searched for other alternatives or ways to calibrate the mouse but haven't come up with anything.

Interestingly enough, when going to take a screen recording of the issue, it turns out that my screen recorder shows the click as if it was accurate, even though my monitor doesn't display it correctly. To illustrate the issue, I took a screen recording and an actual video of the physical monitor at the same time. You can clearly see how in the second video, the crosshairs are below and to the right of where the actual line is drawn:

Screen recording: https://imgur.com/a/wu0UVqf

Video: https://imgur.com/a/DBxtBfC

This makes me think that the problem isn't the mouse at all, but rather something with the display settings, but I have no idea what would cause this. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I have has Windows 11 Pro for near 2 years now and no issue with Mouse Pointer location. 3 Machines including 1 Insider machine. Try:  New mouse driver, new video driver, and totally new mouse.

Comment: Go into *Control Panel > Mouse*, Pointer Options tab, and under Visibility enable "Display Pointer Trails", and then set the slide to the least amount. This should make your mouse use software-rendered mouse mode. If it fixes the problem, let me know.

Comment: @harrymc That worked! Thank you for the suggestion and the details! Any thoughts as to what may have caused this? It looks like I can find other utilities that will hopefully allow me to use the software-rendered mouse without the flicker from the trail, but curious if there is a root cause I could be looking into instead.

Comment: See also https://superuser.com/questions/1531888/mouse-cursor-hotspot-offset-from-visible-cursor-location

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go into *Control Panel > Mouse*, Pointer Options tab, and under Visibility enable "Display Pointer Trails", and then set the slide to the least amount. This should make your mouse use software-rendered mouse mode.

Other methods I found on the internet are :

- Switch to the inverted cursor set.
- [SoftCursor](https://www.monitortests.com/forum/Thread-SoftCursor)
  is a simple program to switch between hardware and
  software mouse cursor rendering in Windows.
  It's from 2012 but might still work.